# Restrict access of other linux user to docker container

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have two linux users, named as: ubuntu and my_user
Now I build a simple Docker image and also run the Docker container 
In my docker-compose.yml, I volume mount some of the files from local machine to the container, which were created by 'ubuntu' user.

Now if I login by 'my_user', and access the docker container created by 'ubuntu' user using docker exec command, then I am able to access any files that are present in the container.

My requirement is to restrict the access of 'my_user', to access the content of Docker container that was created by 'ubuntu' user.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Not with the core functionality of the Moby/Docker Engine; multi-tenant support and user-management / role-based access control is out of scope, but platforms , such as Docker Enterprise Edition provide that functionality

Comment: Hi  jonrsharpe, actually I want my container data to be secured such that only one linux user can access those container contents, no other linux user should be able to perform changes in the container data.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to achieve currently. If your user can execute Docker commands, it means effectively that the user has root privileges, therefore it's impossible to prevent this user from accessing any files.

Comment: Can we use any third party utility to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can add "ro",means readOnly after the data volumn.Like this

HOST:CONTAINER:ro

Or you can add ReadOnly properties in your docker-compose.yml

Here is an example how to specify read-only containers in docker-compose:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

@surabhi, There is only option to restrict file access by adding fields in docker-compose file.

`read_only: flag to set the volume as read-only`

`nocopy: flag to disable copying of data from a container when a volume is created`

You can find more information [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-3)

Answer (score 0):

You could install and run a sshd in that container, map port 22 to an available host port and manage the user accessibility via ssh keys.
This would not allow the user to manage things via docker commands but would give that user access to that container.